# Hide Content (Library) from unauthorized user in SharePoint Site Content

Tags: sharepoint, hide, directory, document

Is there a way to hide content (library) in sharepoint under site content? I tried removing permissions but it only hides files inside the library. My goal is to completely hide the library from unauthorized user so that they will not have an idea that the library as it contains confidential information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using subsite will work as a workaround. By default, subsites are hidden to users without permission under site content (viewlst)